# Q_PROPERTY with parameterized read and write accessors

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a `Configuration` that holds some basic information about file locations like download, install, picture, music, document etc. location.
These are currently exposed to QML using `Q_PROPERTY`. They all have their own accessors:

`Q_PROPERTY(QUrl download_location READ download_location WRITE set_download_location NOTIFY download_location_changed)`

These accessors basically do all the same stuff and I'd like to get rid of all this redundant code I have to write.

My first idea is to have a little nested class `FileLocation` that provides get, set and validation functions. But then, how would I connect these to the `Q_PROPERTY`?

Also, if I had something like a static functions which took parameters, (e.g. `check_validity( QUrl location )`), how would I hand over this parameter from QML side?

I think I'm on the wrong path here, so my question is how to keep redundant code in the context of `Q_PROPERTY` within reasonable limits, avoiding to write loads and loads of get, set and changed functions for very similar objects?

Here's some more code:

```
class Configuration : public QObject
{
  QObject

  Q_PROPERTY(QUrl download_location READ download_location WRITE set_download_location NOTIFY download_location_changed)
  Q_PROPERTY(QUrl music_location READ music_location WRITE set_music_location NOTIFY music_location_changed)
  ...

signals:
  void download_location_changed();
  void music_location_changed();
  ...

public slots:
  void set_download_location(QUrl location)
  {
    download_location = location;
    emit download_location_changed(download_location);
  }

  void set_music_location(QUrl location)
  {
    music_location = location;
    emit music_location_changed(music_location);
  }
  ...

private:
  QUrl download_location,
       music_location,
       ...;
}
```

So as you see there's a lot of recurring code that does the same, and I'd like to damp that down a little. How do I do that? I was thinking about some general functions set, get, changed etc. that get the member to work on was a parameter. But then I didn't know how to hand over which member to work on from qml.

I just found out about the possibility to expose C++ classes to qml via `qmlRegisterType(...)` - maybe this is the way to go here?

Comment: Can you post more code? I struggle to see what the problem is.

Comment: Which code is redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go for an evil macro:

```
#define IMPL(data, name) \
    inline decltype(data) name() const { return data; } \
    inline void set_##name(decltype(data) value) { if (value != data) { data = value; emit name##Changed();} }
```

Of course, if you don't need any extra stuff, you can simply use a MEMBER property and have Qt auto generate accessors for you.

This will however not work if you need to do custom things in the accessors, the macro will, just add your stuff to it.

Lastly, when you declare a `Q_PROPERTY`, you can right-click the property, go to refactoring, and select "generate missing members...", Qt will generate the default stubs for the accessors, and you will only have to add your custom stuff in. The downside to this is it has the nasty habit of putting the generated code in the silliest place possible, so if you want your class to look neat, you have to move it by hand.

`qmlRegisterType()` is when you want to register a type so it can be created in QML, you generally don't have to do anything to access a `QObject` derived object from QML - it works for `QObject` derivatives, you only need to register a metatype for types which do not have meta information generated.

**Last but not least** - I don't see any point in having your configuration as a C++ object, you can just as well do it in QML, and use [Qt.labs.settings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) to make your settings persistent. C++ is optimal for performance critical parts only. If you do your configuration in QML, you don't need to worry about any of that boilerplate code, as it is all automatic in QML, no need to write accessors, no need to recompile your project on every tiny change.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out various options. I've seen the [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) in our code even, need to figure out if it's not used consequently enough or if there are reasons not to do it as you suggested.

Comment: @DenverCoder21 - `QSettings` is from the "olden days", sure it can work in QML projects as well, but QML has the `Settings` element, which is much easier to use, if you use QML there is no good reason to use the old settings class, unless you want tight control over how settings are stored. With QML `Settings` it is all automatic, most likely using the same scheme for storage as `QSettings` by default, with the latter you can have custom settings storage scheme. Or if you have some settings type which is unsupported, in QML only stuff like strings and numbers is supported, usually its enough.

Comment: The reason I see to keep `QSettings` over `Settings` is the ability to have a centralized place for the settings, those living exclusively in C++ included. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @DenverCoder21 - if it works for you then it is ok. From my experience I learned that the most valuable resource is time, and in QML everything is done more quickly, so I keep most of my application code there, C++ is only reserved when its use is unavoidable. Keep in mind you can access QML object properties from C++ easily.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but: How so? (Accessing the QML properties from C++) If've found `findChild` for this, are there other ways?
Besides that thanks a ton for your patient and thorough help.

Comment: Once you find the object with `findChild()` you can store it in a `QObject*`, and then you simply `object->property("propName")`